# RDF triple stores that allow reification

Tags: rdf, triplestore, reification

Is there a triple store that provides built-in support for reification?

What one would like is - on entering a RDF triple in the datastore, a URI corresponding to the entered triple is generated and output; this URI can then become the object of another triple.

Google-fu did not reveal any answers. Or maybe the query is missing the appropriate words. Looking between blazegraph, allegrograph, neo4j and likes.

Comment: I mean, you mentioned Allegrograph, why not reading their docs then to see that they do support some kind of triple ID for reification? And Jena as well as Blazegraph support RDF* to workaround the verbose standard RDF reification.

Comment: Some notes in Russian, but with many links: https://m.habr.com/ru/post/451206, sections V.1.2, V.1.3, V.2. _"became object of another triple"_ — really _object_, not subject?